# Fast swipe movement of GameObject does not collide with Colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I am working on a Unity game in a 2D environment. The player `GameObject` has a `Rigidbody2D` attached. It moves horizontally when swiping. When swipe is too fast, it does not collide with the `Colliders`. Maybe it changes its transform position before detecting collision? It does not happen when the swipe is slow.

Comment: You cannot test for equal, instead you need a range so when moving fast you may pass through the equal condition and not get an exact equal.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your problem I am assuming you are moving your object in the `Update()` function (please correct me if not).  This means you are moving the object a certain amount every frame.  However, Unity checks colliders and does physics calculations on a different time interval (Fixed Timestep, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html).

Just before the objects collide, the colliders are checked.  Unity calculates colliders every `Fixed Timestep` (default 0.02 times a second).  If unity does not detect a collision it means your objects intersect for less time than the `Fixed Timestep`, or in other words, they are moving very fast (like you describe your situation).  One (bad) way to fix this would be to decrease the amount of time in between physics calculations.  However, this would greatly decrease your programs efficiency.

**Instead, consider moving your object in the function `FixedUpdate()` so that the object only moves every time the physics checks for a collision. This should fix your problem.**

Take a look at the 3rd answer (by Garth-Smith):
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rigidbody-2d-wont-collide-with-another-object-when-its-moving-really-fast.248786/

I particularly want to highlight the part:

> If you have a Rigidbody2D, you should be moving it in FixedUpdate()
>   using rigidbody2D.MovePosition(Vector2). This will move the
>   Rigidbody2D through space, instead of teleporting it from point A to
>   point B.

The second part about Raycasts should not be necessary for your problem, but if you continue to experience problems your can use them to check a range as jdweng stated in his comment.

Here are a couple places to learn about Raycasts if you are unfamiliar with them:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/raycasting

Comment: Thank you very much. I was moving the gameobject in Fixed Update. 
i am moving my object by swiping as, 

transform.position += transform.right * _hMovement * transformSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

I am going through the references you have given.

Answer (score 1):

If the movement of your object is too fast it will simply ignore the collision since it never touches the actual collider - it just skips it.

In order to fix this you need to predict when that collision will happen and trigger it at correct moment.

Setting collision detection to Continuous as **pixlark** said might help if the swipe is not too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the collision detection mode for your Rigidbody2D is set to `Continuous` or `Continuous Dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

simple
go to the rigidbody of the object and change the c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).